# How to go back to the first line of a file without re-instantiating Bufferedreader?

Tags: java

```
        for(String column: columnHeaders){

            loadFile(); // Here BufferedReader gets instantiated

            String header =getLineReader().readLine();

            if(header!=null)
            {
                while (( line=getLineReader().readLine())!=null )
                {
                    cellValue =StatUtils.getCellValue(line,getColumnNumberByName(column));

                    csvColumn.addRowElement(cellValue,null);                        
                }                   

            }   

            closeStreams(); // closing the Reader
        }
```

For every column I need to read the csv-file from the 1st to last.
The text file can be very big(100 columns and 5000000 rows).

Now, createing a BufferedReader instance for each column - 
1) Is it going to hamper the performance?
2) Is there any way to create Reader once and whenever it reaches to the last line, in next iteration, it will start from the beginning....

As I said, the file could be very big, so, I don't want to cache it into memory.

Any suggestion/comments?

thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL databases were invented to do this kind of job in a subsecond.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of creating a new `BufferedReader` for each column is going to be negligible compared to the cost of reading in the entire "very big" file all over again.

Whenever you're worried about performance, the first step you should take is to measure. Is your current implementation *actually* slower than you'd like? If it seems fast enough then leave it alone.

If it turns out that it is slower than you'd like then the best way to "optimize" would be to read the file once rather than once for each column you care about. Instead of taking a single column name, you could take a `Map` of column names to "column processors". Each "column processor" would be given successive values for its column, and compute whatever it is that it's supposed to compute (eg: a sum, an average, a sum of squares, or even just storing values in a collection).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be an issue. BufferedReader by default only caches up to 4096 bytes of the file. Hence, the resources needed to create a new BufferedReader, compared to trying to scan back to the start of the file are minimal.

The behaviour you're using seems to scanner the entire file for each column. If you're having performance problems, then this is most likely the source of the problem (not the creation of new BufferedReaders). Try establishing what the headers for the file are (ie, how many columns you will need) and then processing the data row by row, rather than column by column.

If you really, really want to seek to anywhere in the file then try looking at [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Comment: Thanks Dunes,I'll keep in mind about the resouce needs to BufferedReader. And again, as you've said, I think I'll use RandomAccessFile.seek(0)...

Comment: one more question: If I use RandomAccessFile- is it going to cache the whole file at once and then be able to go to the first line by calling seek(0)... What I menat, If my file size is 2GBs, it will be a memory chocking...

Comment: IO almost never reads any amount of data into a memory cache at all. All reads and writes tend to go straight to / from disk. This can have its own bottle necks as hard disks are slow. Buffered classes are an exception as they have a buffer in memory which allows them to read more data from disk in one go, thus increasing their performance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear lord.  Your problem is going to be performance of this algorithm.  You're essentially writing a O(N^2) algorithm over a very large set of data.  It isn't going to perform well anyway.  You need to figure out a way to potentially store portions of this in memory, or use some sort of rolled up metrics you could use instead of rescanning everything you just scanned.

But, anyway, you can use java.io.Reader.reset() to return the beginning of the file if you underlying Readers/InputStream support it.  FileReader usually does.  Knock yourself out kid.  You'll shoot your eye out.